# Possible to emulate the lack of certain system features (such as webcam) in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I'm a web developer and I'm working with webrtc in a new application.
OS X has no easy way to disable my webcam and microphone and I'm wanting to test / design UI components based on lack of webcam / lack of microphone.

Is there a way to disable or emulate that I do not have those features so that the browser won't take over and ask me to allow camera access? etc?

Comment: what about fake media with an argument at the launch of Chrome  `--use-fake-device-for-media-stream` ?

Comment: That just replaces the camera with a different image though... I'm looking to tell the browser that there is no camera installed on the computer.

Comment: Looking for something similar too.